# Best way to use an email signature with CodeIgniter Email Class

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

How can I add an signature to emails I send using CodeIgniter's Email Class, for example add the following at the bottom of each email:

> Joe Bloggs, Company, City, Tel Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use views for this functionality.

In your views, you can add your signatures directly:

```
// views/email_message.php
<h1>My Email Message</h1>
<p>Content</p>
<hr />
<p>Joe Bloggs, Company, Blah</p>
```

Or, better yet, I'd create a signature view and pass the data to it:

```
// views/email_message.php
<?= $this->load->view('email/message', $message_data(), TRUE) ?>
<?= $this->load->view('email/signature', $signature_data(), TRUE) ?>
```

Either way, you can pass this to your email message:

```
// in your controller
$message = $this->load->view('views/email_message', $data(), TRUE);

// configure email options, etc.
...
$this->email->message($message);

// send the email
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this for simplicity:

```
$this->email->message('Whatever your message is.' . '\n\n Joe Bloggs, Company, Blah');
```

Comment: Will be sending emails from many parts of the application so want a solution that lets me hold the signature in one variable and reuse throughout application.